# Setting localStorage properties in an ng-change event

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, local-storage

Is setting `localStorage` properties in an `ng-change` event a good idea?

I'm setting a range value this way:

```
<input type="range" ng-model="vol" ng-change="change()">

 $scope.change=function() {      
   window.localStorage['vol']=$scope.vol;
 }
```

When I change the range, multiple events are fired.

I can set the value only if after some `ms` the value haven't changed, but does it deserve this extra complexity?

Comment: you are passing action in your `$scope.change` function but in html you are not sending any action in your change function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bad idea to mix plain js code with angular scope. 
If you want to use HTML5 features like local storage then you should use an angular module that encapsulates it like ngStorage:
https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage

Comment: Thanks, it's good to know it, but is it right to use `$localStorage` in a `range` `ng-change`?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with it. However you should ask yourself whether you really need local Storage for this matter? Remember that local storage is a persistence model that will store this value even after the client closes his browser. If you need this kind of behavior (or perhaps communicate between tabs) then it's good if not then just use a custom angular service.

Comment: Great. I need to persist them as they are user settings that must be avaliable after an app restart (it's a hybrid app)